# JavaScript is not redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

My Javascript is not redirecting. Here is what I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    Search: <input id="searchterm" type="text" name="searchterm">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="processFormData()">
</form>

<script>
    function processFormData()
    {
        var term = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;
        window.location = window.location.href + term;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want user to be redirected to a specified url no matter of the url in browser. This should be universal on different machines. I am new to JS, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move the `onclick` event handler declaration to the `<form>` tag. Next, change it into an `onsubmit` event handler declaration. Finally add a `return` in front of it (to prevent default event handling, i.e. actually submitting the form):

```
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="return processFormData();">
     Search: <input id="searchterm" type="text" name="searchterm" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
 </form>
```

Then also add a `return false;` at the end of `processFormData`:

```
function processFormData()
{
    var term = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;
    window.location = window.location.href + term;
    return false;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwcvq7bf/

Comment: I found this solution best. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Use **location.host**. Try this:

```
function processFormData()
{
    var term = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;
    window.location = "http://"+location.host+"/"+term;
    return false;
}
```

And,

```
<form method="POST">
   Search: <input id="searchterm" type="text" name="searchterm">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return processFormData()">
</form>
```

So, now your url will be like this: **http://www.example.com/searchTerm**

Comment: This will not solve the main problem, namely using the wrong event handler.

Comment: @HaukeP. I updated the answer. Check it now and let me know if your are still facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the url itself,

```
window.location = "url"+term;
```

If you wanna get only the hostname(http://www.example.com),

```
window.location = location.hostname +"/"+term;
```

or If you wanna get the href(http://www.example.com/home/about.htm),

```
window.location = location.href +"/"+term;
```